# sort number and alphabet string using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sorting, type-conversion

I have a column with `string type in my database that contains these value :

```
410
AFP-EXEC
412
411
AFP-EXEP
```

So i want to sort them as you can see :

```
_materialIssueVoucherRepository.Get().OrderBy(i=>int.Parse(i.Code)).ToList()
```

But it returns an  obvious error `Convert error string to int`,The result should be like this :

```
410
411 
412
AFP-EXEC
AFP-EXEP
```

The Alphabet part is not important,Can i do that in EF?

Comment: OrderBy(e => e.Code) should work fine for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int temp;
_materialIssueVoucherRepository
        .Get()
        .OrderBy(i => int.TryParse(i.Code, out temp) ? temp : int.MaxValue)
        .ToList()
```

---

it sounds like you want to ignore the non-numeric characters in the string and then use the integers as part of the sorting.  You can try:

```
.OrderBy(i => int.Parse(new string(i.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()))
```

which will grab only the integers from the string for a comparison, though it's not very pretty.

Comment: it would be if that were a requirement, but I went off where he said `The Alphabet part is not important`

Comment: true :) missed that

Comment: @Jonesopolis your code doesn't work for these data :30908
31880
30910
32159
ARP-PH22-MCS-068
HOV-0002
MD-0003
MD-0004
MD-0005
MD-0006
MD-0007
MD-0008
MD-0009
MD-0010
MD-0011
MD-0012
MD-0013
MD-0014
MD-0015
MD-0022
MD-0023
MD-0025
MD-0026
MD-0028
32267
32268
32260
32261
32274
HOV-0005
32369
32385
32388
32384
32383
32404
HOV-AFP-0006
HOV-AFP-0008
32579
HOV-AFP-0011
HOV-AFP-0016
32650
32651
32652 why ?

Comment: @EhsanAkbar - When you say doesn't work, please specify what is meant by that

Comment: It orders all the integers in order and puts the alphanumeric strings at the end.  Which is what that code is designed to do.  It sounds like you have more requirements that weren't stated in the question.

Comment: And it doesn't work for these item too :2
15

39
41
43
53
57
59
48
51
AFP-PIP-0060
AFP-PIP-0063
AFP-PIP-0079
MD-HO
AFP-PIP-0074
AFP-PIP-0065
AFP-PIP-0067
AFP-PIP-0091
AFP-PIP-0086
AFP-PIP-0087
AFP-PIP-0090
AFP-PIP-0092
AFP-PIP-0093
AFP-PIP-0094
HOV-AFP-0005
AFP-PIP-0002
AFP-PIP-0005
HOV
AFP-PIP-0106
HOV-0008
AFP-PIP-0110
HOV-00008
HOV-0011
AFP-157
AFP-PIP-0111
AFP-PIP-0112
HOV-AFP-0011
HOV-AFP-0016
AFP-PIP-0116
AFP-PIP-0117
AFP-PIP-0118
AFP-PIP-0119
AFP-PIP-0120
HOV-0011-1
HOV-0011-2
AFP-173

Comment: @EhsanAkbar - please explain what is meant by "it is not working"

Comment: Ok let me ask another question

Comment: actually i think i see what you are saying, look at my edit @EhsanAkbar

Comment: @Jonesopolis icheck it it doesn't work .The where clause doesn't solved by c#

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a custom [comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx) for this purpose. Like this:

```
public class AlphanumComparator : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string str1, string str2)
    {
        if (IsNumeric(str1) && IsNumeric(str2))
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(str1) > Convert.ToInt32(str2)) return 1;
            if (Convert.ToInt32(str1) < Convert.ToInt32(str2)) return -1;
            if (Convert.ToInt32(str1) == Convert.ToInt32(str2)) return 0;
        }

        if (IsNumeric(str1) && !IsNumeric(str2))
            return -1;

        if (!IsNumeric(str1) && IsNumeric(str2))
            return 1;

        return String.Compare(str1, str2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public static bool IsNumeric(object value)
    {
        try
        {
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(value.ToString());
            return true;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
_materialIssueVoucherRepository.Get().OrderBy(x => x.Code, new AlphanumComparator()).ToList();
```

Comment: @S.Akbari - The problem with this is that it will order the "numbers" by their alphabetic order and not by their numeric order

Comment: the digit number just sorted by the left digit i mean when my input is :12,15,21,2,100,10,s,a ,output is :12,10,15,100,2,21

Comment: @EhsanAkbar OK. You need a custom comparer. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @S.Akbari let me check it

Comment: your code doesn't work for these data :30908 31880 30910 32159 ARP-PH22-MCS-068 HOV-0002 MD-0003 MD-0004 MD-0005 MD-0006 MD-0007 MD-0008 MD-0009 MD-0010 MD-0011 MD-0012 MD-0013 MD-0014 MD-0015 MD-0022 MD-0023 MD-0025 MD-0026 MD-0028 32267 32268 32260 32261 32274 HOV-0005 32369 32385 32388 32384 32383 32404 HOV-AFP-0006 HOV-AFP-0008 32579 HOV-AFP-0011 HOV-AFP-0016 32650 32651 32652 why